# Can Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman (ECDH) shared secret be used as a static encryption key?

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

I have two parties:

**Alice** who has a static public key **P<sub>A</sub>**

**Bob** who has a static public key **P<sub>B</sub>**

A static shared secret (**S**) is computed with ECDH.

Encryption and MAC keys are computed with a key derivation function:  (**K<sub>ENC</sub>**, **K<sub>MAC</sub>**) = KDF(**S**)

The two parties send messages to each other, encrypted and authenticated respectively using **K<sub>ENC</sub>** and **K<sub>MAC</sub>**. The encrypted messages are also stored in this encrypted form.

My question: how secure is using these static derived keys (**K<sub>ENC</sub>** and **K<sub>MAC</sub>**) in the long run if I want encryption and authenticity, but I do not care about forward secrecy.

Comment: This is basically what NaCl's `crypto_box` does.

Comment: You may want to look up the NIST document on (EC)DH. In there static-static DH actually does use a random component for deriving keys. This won't provide you forward secrecy of course, but it's at least more secure than just keeping the same key.

Answer (score 3):

This usage is theoretically sound assuming you do not desire Perfect Forward Secrecy, but will exacerbate attacks on the block cipher by providing potentially very many messages encrypted under the same key, and will exacerbate side channel attacks by repeatedly deriving the static secret (allowing many chances to catch small fragments and re-assemble).

Consider also that if users A and B have a static secret, then party C who obtains either A or B's key, can recover the shared secrets in both directions, and thus impersonate either party, to either party.

Edit: Another notable attack: party D, who does not have either key but can capture packets, can replay any message that A or B sent, and they can send it in either direction at any time, of course the keys will still be valid so the message will appear authentic. This can be just as effective as a full break in many cases.

Comment: As A and B use not just static but also identical keys that it is impossible to distinguish between messages send by A or B. So you'd need additional security measures to make sure that messages from A are not replayed back to A.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there's another subtle attack I've failed to mention as well. Of course rolling your own crypto inherently features this danger of overlooking subtle but fatal details.